# Retrieve total cache size in memory cache wrapper class

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a class (which is instantiated as a Singleton) wrapped around ASP.NET's IMemoryCache dependency like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System;

namespace Lambgoat.Web.Cache
{
    public class CacheStrategy : ICacheStrategy
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
        public CacheStrategy(IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _cache = cache;
        }

        public T Set<T>(string key, T value, DateTimeOffset expiration, int size = 1)
        {
            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSize(size).SetAbsoluteExpiration(expiration);
            return _cache.Set(key, value, cacheEntryOptions);
        }

        public bool Exists<T>(string id, out T value) where T : new()
        {
            bool exists = _cache.TryGetValue<T>(id, out T cacheValue);
            value = cacheValue ?? new T();
            return exists;
        }

        public void Invalidate(string id) => _cache.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

When the Set() method is called, I would like to check if the total cache size is close to the size limit I set in the Startup.cs like this:

```
if (totalCacheSize + 10 > 1024) {
    _cache.Compact(.33);
}
```

My problem is retrieving the total cache size; how would one go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you store the cache instance as a concrete [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) rather than `IMemoryCache`, you can access its only public property, `Count`. Everything else related to size is internal.

```
private readonly MemoryCache _cache;
public CacheStrategy(IMemoryCache cache)
{
    _cache = (MemoryCache)cache;
}
```

Then inspect `Count`:

```
if (_cache.Count > 1024) {
    _cache.Compact(.33);
}
```

Since `Count` represents number of entries, there's no way to know how much actual memory usage this corresponds to.